# What is the right way to count number of records returned by group by query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I count the number of actual records returned by a group by query

For e.g

```
-- Exec SP_GET_ITEM_STOCK 0,10,NULL,'Charger'
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_ITEM_STOCK]
    @startRowIndex int ,
    @pageSize int,
    @ItemID bigint = null,
    @ItemName varchar(250) = null
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQLWHERE varchar(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 'WITH DATA AS (
                select 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item_ID) ''SNo'',
                    Item_ID,
                    Item_Name,
                    SUM(Inward) as Total_Purchase,
                    SUM(Outward) as Total_Sale,
                    (sum(Inward) - sum(outward))as Balance_Stock'
    Set @SQLWHERE = ' from Item_Ledger_Details where Active = 1'

    IF @ItemID IS NOT NULL and @ItemID <> ''
    SET @SQLWHERE = @SQLWHERE + ' and Item_ID = ' + CONVERT(varchar,@ItemID) + ''

    IF @ItemName IS NOT NULL and @ItemName <> ''
    SET @SQLWHERE = @SQLWHERE + ' and Item_Name like ''%' + @ItemName + '%'''

    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SQLWHERE + ' group by Item_ID,Item_Name) SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE SNo BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(Varchar,@startRowIndex) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(Varchar,@startRowIndex+@pageSize) + ' ORDER BY SNo'
    EXEC(@SQL +';SELECT COUNT(*) ''Count'' '+ @SQLWHERE)
    print(@SQL)
END
```

Which returns:

[image]

I need to count the above first result records to get 1 + 1 = 2 in second result where I get count = 48

Comment: Ugh, why use dynamic SQL when you can easily avoid it?

Comment: There is no need of dynamic query. Just print the query, add it to your question, and I'll help you from there

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Continue Anand Answer. I've just modify his query. Below query is solved my answer. But I think may be this query needs optimization.

```
-- SP_GET_ITEM_STOCK 0,10,NULL,NULL
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_ITEM_STOCK]
@startRowIndex int,
@pageSize int,
@ItemID bigint = null,
@ItemName varchar(250) = null
AS
    BEGIN
    Declare @Temp Table (
    SNo bigint,
    Item_ID bigint,
    Item_Name varchar(max),
    Total_Purchase money,
    Total_Sale money,
    Balance_Stock money
);
WITH DATA AS (
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item_ID) as SNo,
    Item_ID,
    Item_Name,
    SUM(Inward) as Total_Purchase,
    SUM(Outward) as Total_Sale,
    (sum(Inward) - sum(outward))as Balance_Stock
from Item_Ledger_Details
where Active = 1
and (coalesce(@ItemID, '') = '' or Item_ID = CONVERT(varchar,@ItemID))
and ( coalesce(@ItemName, '') = '' or  Item_Name like '%' + @ItemName + '%')
group by Item_ID,
    Item_Name
)
insert into @Temp
SELECT * 
FROM DATA 
WHERE SNo BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND @startRowIndex+@pageSize
ORDER BY SNo

select * from @temp
    SELECT COUNT(*) as Count from @temp
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There, I've cleaned it up:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_ITEM_STOCK]
    @startRowIndex int,
    @pageSize int,
    @ItemID bigint = null,
    @ItemName varchar(250) = null
AS
BEGIN

;WITH DATA AS (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Item_ID) as SNo,
        Item_ID,
        Item_Name,
        SUM(Inward) as Total_Purchase,
        SUM(Outward) as Total_Sale,
        (sum(Inward) - sum(outward))as Balance_Stock
    from Item_Ledger_Details
    where Active = 1
    and (coalesce(@ItemID, '') = '' or Item_ID = CONVERT(varchar,@ItemID))
    and ( coalesce(@ItemName, '') = '' or  Item_Name like '%' + @ItemName + '%')
    group by Item_ID,
        Item_Name
)

SELECT * 
FROM DATA 
WHERE SNo BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND @startRowIndex+@pageSize
ORDER BY SNo

SELECT COUNT(*) as Count
from DATA

END
```

Comment: Error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_GET_ITEM_STOCK, Line 30 Invalid object name 'DATA'.

Comment: I've modified your answer and posted above. Have a look?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the semicolon before the CTE. You already have a CTE so there is no need for an additional table variable. This answer should work now.

Comment: Here is an error I found in your code after selecting data code is generate error while counting rows `Invalid object name 'DATA'.`